# Using Pandoc to convert Markdown to Beamer Slides with PDF Bookmarks

Tags: beamer, pandoc, markdown

I recently learned how to use Pandoc and TexLive LaTeX to convert Markdown to Beamer slides. The command I'm using is this:

```
pandoc src/00_local_git.md -t beamer -o slides/00_local_git.pdf
```

However, this does not add each Slide header as a bookmark in the PDF. Is this possible to do? The top of my Markdown file looks like this:

```
---
title:
  - Using Git Locally
author:
  - Phillip Dudley
theme:
  - Copenhagen
---


# What is Git?

Git is a Source Control Management application.

Git is used to perform development in a decentralized manner.

Git uses a remote server to provide a centralized place to hold the source of
truth.

Everything in Git is a local operation.

# Defining terms

* What is SCM?
    * Source Control Management/Manager
    * The tool that tracks the changes made to files that are being watched by
      the SCM tool.
    * Git, SVN, VCS, HG are all SCM tools.
* What is a commit?
    * A `commit` is a point in time after changes in files have been saved that
      that Git is told to record the state of tracked files.
* What is a branch?
    * A `branch` is a mirror image from a point in time of the parent where the
      user can make changes without impacting the parent.
* What is an upstream?
    * An `upstream` is where the original code came from.
* What is a remote?
    * A special server where Git repositories are hosted for other to pull from
      and make their upstream.
```

If this isn't the correct place to post this question, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. This is the right place to ask such questions. It would be helpful if you could also provide a sample `.md` document to play with.

Comment: Where should I post this question? I didn't know if it would be appropriate to be in the TeX.se or StackOverflow.

Comment: You *are* in the right place! (That's what I said.)

Comment: Ah! My dumb eyes mixed the `is the` and added an `n` in there.

Comment: By default, `beamer` doesn't put slide titles into the TOC (which is I think what you want), and there's no simple way to do it. See [Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/56512) for what is involved, but that may not be so simple to do via `pandoc`.

Comment: I'll investigate and update my question if I find anything. I was looking to stick mostly to Markdown because not many I work with are able to do LaTeX nor want to do it. I'll see if I have to make a change or not.